# Binary tree implementation

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I seem to be getting a segmentation fault, and it seems as though the error is coming from the call to tra, but I am unable to see exactly what is wrong with the code that I have written. Really have no clue, any want to give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

```
struct node *tra(struct node * start) {
  struct node * current = start;       
  return current; }

Table ins(Key_Type input, Table table) {
  if ((find(input, table)) == FALSE) {
    struct node *newVal = tra(table -> head, input);
    newVal -> element = input;
```

I have defined a struct node which contains head, left and right elements. I know for sure that tra returns current when it is null, as I am creating a tree which is empty at first, so all nodes will be empty.

Comment: Aww, `new` as a variable name in C code? What if somebody tries to compile it using a C++ compiler?

Comment: I think you need to review what you have posted - the code does not appear complete enough to offer opinions on.

Comment: @H2CO3: but the question is tagged as `c`, and why would he try to compile C code with a C++ compiler. :) easier just to link the object code if he want to write C++ or assembly.

Comment: @H2CO3 There's nothing wrong with naming a variable `new` in C. C programs, except for trivial ones, will not compile under a C++ compiler for a number of reasons (lack of casts from `void *`, to name one), and the naming of a local variable would be the least of the worries.

Comment: @emil How would you compile it on Windows, for example? (Of course, no sane-minded honest man would want to compile on Windows, but anyway). And also, C and C++ are just too closely related for this to not be considered bad practice.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm not saying that it doesn't compile. I'm saying that it's bad style.

Comment: @H2CO3 If the problem isn't in compiling the code with a C++ compiler, then where *is* the problem with that code? In other words, why do you consider it bad practice? Variable names like `old` and `new` are often used in C and are generally considered perfectly valid.

Comment: @user4815162342 "If the problem isn't in compiling the code with a C++ compiler" - **it is.** Your reply was actually suggesting that I though this doesn't compile with a C compiler (which is not true, neither did I assume that).

Comment: @H2CO3 there are no C compilers available for Windows?

Comment: @emil There's MinGW and Cygwin, both outdated and a nightmare to set up (ans anyways everybody uses MSVC++, because they don't even know about the alternatives).

Comment: @user4815162342 I would advise you combine the logic of find'ing with insert'ing. You're going to end up searching twice for the same thing as written (once to see if it is present, once to find where to put it). A function that returns the *address* of the pointer (either the pointer where it current exists (not null) or the pointer where you should insert it (null) would be helpful, since you can use it for *both* your find and your insert logic.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, my answer was suggesting that there's no reason to modify C code because of the non-existent requirement for it to compile with a C++ compiler, **which won't work anyway**, for a number of reasons that have nothing to do with variables named `new`.

Comment: @emil Visual Studio comes with a [C compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384838.aspx) perfectly capable of compiling C code. (We use it every day in production.) To claim otherwise is pure FUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some weird stuff going on there.

```
if (current == NULL)
  return current;
```

Why `return current`? Current is `null`?

```
struct node *new = tra(table -> head, input);
```

`tra` takes a single argument?

I'd recommend you use `gdb`. Learn to use it now, and it will give you the power to answer this question yourself. It's not difficult.

Comment: haha I really don't know what to say. The code is insufficient to do anything but guessing, and OP seems confused :(

Comment: I concur. So tell me. what the hell do I type to send a target comment (@username) to you as the opening character. Having to reach for a cut/paste seems a little harsh =P (btw. you name pastes into an Xcode editor just fine, which frankly surprised me.)

Comment: The first character is a regular `u` ;)

Comment: Ah. ok. i got it . well well done, sir.

Answer (score 1):

`tra` looks suspicious. What is the check for? If `current` is `NULL` return it, else fall of the stack and return trash to the caller.

Comment: I just removed the rest of the code, as it wasn't necessary for this. Let me edit it to make it easier.

Comment: @user1899174 It seems you removed a lot more than necessary to understand your problem. Please post something that is able to reproduce the problem.